# Is any diagramming software exists for MVC pattern with code generation?

Tags: model-view-controller, uml

MVC patter uses delegates to interconnect a lot of class objects with each over. For Qt they are signals and slots, for C# they are events, for Java they are closures. But all diagramming and UML designers i know only operates with inheritance and child-parent composition :(. Is it any software available that allows to draw classes visually, design delegates, connect delegates to endpoints and generate code based on such a 'model'?

The description above may not be accurate: i'm not very deep in terminology. If anyone want any clarification about this question, please comment, i wll clarify what is unclear.

Comment: Forget code generation from diagrams.

Comment: What do you expect of such a CASE tool? UML class diagrams describe the static structure of your code, so code generation may make some sense (to a certain degree). Event signaling / listening / subscribing is a highly dynamic thing, happening somewhere on the object or inside-function (and not the class) level, and might involve business and/or GUI logic. Perhaps it would work in context of an activity diagram, but I suspect then those diagrams would be on the same abstraction level as your code, giving you no benefits over the code.

Comment: Basically i expect a visual designer that supports such things as "outgoing signals" and "signal handler" and can visually design such object relationship. Basic code generation support will allow me, theoretically, to define rules how to transform a diagram into code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can succesfully apply MDA is the other way around. Define the model in a fluent DSL, and generate the diagrams you need out of it.

I've used TogetherJ and Enterprise Architect, but I'm not impressed. Nice diagrams, lousy workflow. I very much prefer a Smalltalk environment (preferably with [MOOSE](http://www.moosetechnology.org/)) and a few diagram generators.

Answer (score 5):

I've had good experiences with [Sparx System's Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/).  You can download a fully functional 30 day trial.

Comment: +1, I love to use Enterprise Architect, but I generally don't use its built-in code generation capabilities; I do prefer to access its model from a C# script so I build my code generator; this gives flexibility to create anything I want

Answer (score 2):

[AndroMDA](http://www.andromda.org/) has support to generate a web user interface from a UML model that defines the flow of an application. See the [Search Criteria Panel](http://www.andromda.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=141:search-criteria-panel&catid=42:getting-started-java&Itemid=89) from the [Getting Started Java](http://www.andromda.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=42&Itemid=89) documentation. If you use the AndroMDA BPM4Struts cartridge, the presentation layer will be MVC based. Not sure this is what you're looking for though.

PS: The history of MDA is not full of successful experiences - and this is an euphemism - and I wouldn't recommend this approach (even less for the presentation layer)

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for something free / open-source, there's always:

[StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/index.php)

Comment: I have checked it, but can't find any way to model signa-to-slot kind of relationship.